# How to create VAO and VBO to use with JOGL?

Tags: jogl, vbo, vao

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630753/jogl-opengl-vbo-how-to-render-vertices/17642149) stackoverflow answer. And tried to run the code given there. But all I get is a pink screen. I reached to a conclusion that the problem lies in the init() method. I have tried to understand how VAO-s and VBO-s work but I still don't get it. Most examples about JOGL either skip over the VAO, VBO part or the parts with VAO or VBO are super complex. Can someone tell me what I did wrong here?:

```
GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glClearDepthf(10.0f);
    gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.6f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);

    gl.glGenBuffers(2, buffers);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.get(0));
    gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 6 * 2, vertexFB, GL3.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.get(1));
    gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 6 * 3, colorFB, GL2.GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, vertexArray);
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vertexArray.get(0));

    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.get(0));
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.get(1));
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

I think I'm somehow binding the VBO-s wrong or something.

https://codeshare.io/299wD0 Full code and shaders. Colors dont show up. It renders the rectangle, but its white. And i can comment out the shader part and i still get white rectangle. It seems like it is not using the shader.

Comment: You don't provide a SSCCE. Have you look at Xerxes' example? https://jogamp.org/cgit/jogl-demos.git/tree/src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java?id=HEAD

Comment: @gouessej I have looked at it. Id say it has too much additional stuff in it makeing it hard to find the pieces of interest. Also why is the buffer created inside display method? Doesent it recreate the buffer each frame? Id like to find something like Xerxes example but made more simple. Basically minimal viable code for rendering using VAO.

Comment: You haven't provided a SSCCE in the meantime. No there's just the minimum code needed to use the programmable pipeline and a lot of comments. Yes, I would have created those buffers only once inside the init method. We can't reduce the complexity of this example because you have a lot more responsibilities in the programmable pipeline (and a lot more with Vulkan by the way).

Comment: @gouessej added codeshare with the code.

Comment: There is a real lack of code to get potential errors, it would help in your case. Don't use wrap, avoid using indirect NIO buffers as JOGL will have to convert them into direct ones.

Comment: Been tryitnh to get more info, but jogl tutorials about shaders and VAO are quite nonexistant.

Comment: Actually, you can use the numerous OpenGL tutorials as JOGL is a binding to OpenGL and OpenGL-ES. Moreover, the example I gave you contains the necessary calls but you claimed that it has too much additional stuff in it.

Comment: Keep in mind that we are volunteers, we aren't paid to maintain JOGL, there are no sponsors most of the time.

Comment: @gouessej I want a clear and concise example on Initialising shaders, creating the VBO then the VAO and then rendering it all. Most examples have a lot of extra stuff in it like the projectsions and rotations and matrix multiplications and what not. Making the examples not clear anymore and making hard to see what is nesessary to get anything to render at all. Basically i want example with the ABSOLUTE minimum for VAO to work with colors.

Comment: Xerxes' example does that. When you have to replicate fixed pipeline functions in the programmable pipeline, you have to deal with projections, rotations, matrix multiplications, etc because OpenGL no longer does it for you. Moreover, we are volunteers, we can't write some very specific tutorials for each use case. Actually, Xerxes' example contains a lot of comments, it might give the impression that it's very complicated whereas it isn't, those comments are very useful, they just occupy a lot of space.